# Referencing parent pom's target folder for Cucumber reports in multi module maven projects

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have a multi module maven project for wich I generate Cucumber reports in each module. Now I need to change the target location for the generated reports to the target folder in the root pom's directory.
Is it posssible to do something like this?

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty", "html:path-to-parent-pom/target/testresult"})
```

For other reports generated with `maven-project-info-reports-plugin` there is a configuration option that solves this issue.

```
<aggregate>true</aggregate>
```

Is there something like this for Cucumber reports?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Json Report option in Cucumber and Json report will read by Maven. I think that's what I did. To allow Json option here is

```
 @CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty",
        "json:target/testresult.json" }
```

and I used this plugin for configuration http://damienfremont.com/2015/07/30/how-to-cucumber-test-reporting-plugin-with-maven-and-java/